# org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted: Write not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm using a Python GATT client software ([Bleak](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) over an RPI, in order to scan, connect and read/write values from BLE devices, to collect the status of them.

The actual problem comes when it reaches the "write to GATT characteristic" time, which eventually ends in "Write not permitted" error.

---

I use the following scanning method:

```
device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(mac_addr, timeout=5.0)
```

Once the device is found, I access to it and do the following:

```
async with BleakClient(address) as client:
    print(f"Connected: {client.is_connected}")

    # Subscribe to desired GATT characteristic UUID
    await client.start_notify(CHAR_UUID_TO_READ, notification_handler)
    await asyncio.sleep(2.0)

    ...

    # Write one byte to a different GATT characteristic UUID
    # which will alter the value displayed on the CHAR_UUID_TO_READ
    await client.write_gatt_char(CHAR_UUID_TO_WRITE, b'\x01')
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

    ...

    # Once found the specified end-of-text pattern, it shall disconnect 
    # from the device
    await client.stop_notify(char_uuid)
```

By proceeding as described, I get the following error:

```
[org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted] Write not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scan_and_connect.py", line 462, in main
await client.start_notify(CHAR_UUID_TO_READ, notification_handler)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 931, in start_notify
assert_reply(reply)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/utils.py", line 23, in assert_reply
raise BleakDBusError(reply.error_name, reply.body)
bleak.exc.BleakDBusError: [org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted] Write not permitted
```

Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the characteristic writable?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKotzjan, yes it is (write only), not read and write.

Comment: It's a little hard to read the error message but it appears to be giving the error during the `start_nofify` command. My assumption is that it is having a problem writing to the `CHAR_UUID_TO_READ` descriptor to subscribe to notifications. Have you tried having `sudo btmon` in another terminal while your script is running to see what errors are reported in there?